# Does this scabbard really exist?

Tags: part-identification, ninjago

My son has seen a kind of backpack scabbard in a Ninjago magazine, and would like to get a real one for his collection. It holds a single large sword - all the others he has hold two swords, either in parallel (in the style of the Witcher!) or in the form of a cross.

[image: this]

I have found [this](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4634387) unofficial 3D model, but would rather be pointed towards the real thing if there is such a thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to me drawn item might not represent existing element accurately. It is very close to [Minifigure Armor Shoulder Pad Single with Scabbard for 2 Katanas](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=23983&idColor=77#T=C&C=77). Could be pictured at an odd angle.

[image]

OR

Some modification of [Minifigure Armor Shoulder Pads with Scabbard for Two Katanas and Bar Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=65183#T=C)

[image]

The only one I could find for holding single katana is [Minifigure Armor Shoulder Pad Single with Star Lettering and Scabbard for 1 Katana](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=41162), but shoulder piece is covering minifigure's right side.

[image]

There are some other elements that could hold two katanas:

[Minifigure Armor Shoulder Pads with Scabbard for Two Katanas](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98132#T=C)

[image]

[Minifigure Scabbard for Two Katanas](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=88290)

[image]